# Nock + multipart form data = No match for request

Tags: node.js, form-data, boundary, nock

I have a problem with testing my node application using using [Nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock). I record all requests via `nock.recorder.rec`, but among them there multipart request. I use [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data). This module put the **boundary** to request body, when i use function `form.append`. The problem is that the boundary is always different and when i run tests with recorded data Nock can't find match for request (because boyundary in request body not what was when recording). What can be done? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I can make a dirty hack: before calling `form.append` method write `form._boundary = 'myboundary`'. In this case, boundary always be static and tests will be held. But static boundary can be a bad decision .. Maybe manually generate boundary on certain algorithm?

Answer (score 6):

I came across a similar problem. What you can do is use the second argument as as a function instead and match the object you're trying to send as form data. Example:

```
nock('localhost')
  .post('/url', function(body) {
    return JSON.stringify(body) === JSON.stringify(params);
  })
  .reply(200, 'some data');
```

More on that in the documentation here: https://github.com/pgte/nock#specifying-request-body

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use a `RegExp`:

```
nock(baseUrl)
    .post(`/url', /form-data; name="field"[^]*value/m)
    .reply(200, 'some data');
```

Note

- the beginning of input character (`^`) within the regexp (because the form data might contain line breaks)
- the `m` flag for **m**ultiline
- the example above corresponds to: `form.append('field', value);`
- for a real-world example see [here](https://github.com/schnatterer/photostationtagdownloader/blob/e69b5d570361fa2b39955def16dee31a7763623c/test/downloader.test.js#L239). This also shows how to use a variable within the regex, using the `RegExp` class.